# wrapping keywords in hyperlinks - replacement takes place infinitely many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to wrap specific keywords in hyperlinks, but replacements take place inifitely many times:

```
var replacements = [
    { txt: 'magicFunction', link: 'https://www.example.com/doc/api/magicFunction.htm' },
];
$(function() {
    $.each(replacements,
        function() {
            var searchWord = this.txt;
            var link = this.link;
            $('body:contains("' + searchWord + '")').each(function() {
                var newHtml = $(this).html().replace(searchWord,
                    '<a href="'+link+'">' + searchWord + '</a>');
                $(this).html(newHtml);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

I'd need a condition around the matching part to say that *if is already wrapped in a hyperlink then don't do anything*, or some other workaround.

How can it be fixed?

https://jsfiddle.net/m4j28s13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all nodes in the body but exclude all `<a>` elements:

```
$('body *:not(a):contains("' + searchWord + '")').each(...)
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
var replacements = [{
  txt: 'magicFunction',
  link: 'https://www.example.com/doc/api/magicFunction.htm'
}, ];
$.each(replacements,
  function() {
    var searchWord = this.txt;
    var link = this.link;
    $('body *:not(a):contains("' + searchWord + '")').each(function() {
      var newHtml = $(this).html().replace(searchWord,
        '<a href="' + link + '">' + searchWord + '</a>');
      $(this).html(newHtml);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This sentence mentions magicFunction() in a paragraph.</p>

<p>The following code block (from API reference) mentions it too:</p>

<code class="code-block hljs lua">if a==0 then
    h=magicFunction('foo')
end</code>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update: to handle cases where an `<a>` element may contain nested tags that contain the replacement word, another solution will be to actually replace `:contains` with a custom guard clause in the callback, which will check if the child textNodes contain the keyword. If it does, then perform the replacement:

```js
var replacements = [{
  txt: 'magicFunction',
  link: 'https://www.example.com/doc/api/magicFunction.htm'
}, ];

$.each(replacements,
  function() {
    var searchWord = this.txt;
    var link = this.link;
    $('*:not(a, script)').each(function() {
      const textContent = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
      }).text();

      if (textContent.match(searchWord)) {
        var newHtml = $(this).html().replace(searchWord,
          '<a href="' + link + '">' + searchWord + '</a>');
        $(this).html(newHtml);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This sentence mentions magicFunction() in a paragraph.</p>

<p>The following code block (from API reference) mentions it too:</p>

<code class="code-block hljs lua">if a==0 then
    h=magicFunction('foo')
end</code>

<p>This mention is already linked (should not be linked again): <a class="postlink" href="//www.example2.com/doc/api/magicFunction"><code style="display:inline">magicFunction</code></a></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! There is however one issue when the existing HTML is`<a class="postlink" href="//www.example2.com/doc/api/magicFunction"><code style="display:inline">magicFunction</code></a>`, then it becomes `<a class="postlink" href="//www.example2.com/doc/api/<a href=" https:="" www.example.com="" doc="" api="" magicfunction.htm"="">magicFunction</a>"><code style="display:inline">magicFunction</code>`